# Calculate time difference in milliseconds using Pandas

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe `timings` as follows:

```
    start_ms                     end_ms
0   2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z     2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z
1   2020-09-01T08:11:20.652Z     2020-09-01T08:11:20.662Z
2   2020-09-01T08:11:20.670Z     2020-09-01T08:11:20.688Z
```

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between the `start_ms` and `end_ms` of each row in milliseconds, i.e. I wish to get the result

```
    start_ms                     end_ms                       diff
0   2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z     2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z     0
1   2020-09-01T08:11:20.652Z     2020-09-01T08:11:20.662Z     10
2   2020-09-01T08:11:20.670Z     2020-09-01T08:11:20.688Z     18
```

I can convert the timestamp to datetime column by column, but I'm not sure if the order of the values are retained.

```
start_ms_time = pd.to_datetime(timings['start_ms'])
end_ms_time = pd.to_datetime(timings['end_ms'])
```

Is it possible to convert the timestamps to datetime inside `timings`, and add the time difference column? Do I even need to convert to get the difference? How do I calculate the time difference in milliseconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract columns by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and then use [`Series.dt.components`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.components.html):

```
start_ms_time = pd.to_datetime(timings['start_ms'])
end_ms_time = pd.to_datetime(timings['end_ms'])

timings['diff'] = end_ms_time.sub(start_ms_time).dt.components.milliseconds
print (timings)
                   start_ms                    end_ms  diff
0  2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z  2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z     0
1  2020-09-01T08:11:20.652Z  2020-09-01T08:11:20.662Z    10
2  2020-09-01T08:11:20.670Z  2020-09-01T08:11:20.688Z    18
```

Or [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) with multiple by `1000` and cast to integers:

```
timings['diff'] = end_ms_time.sub(start_ms_time).dt.total_seconds().mul(1000).astype(int)
print (timings)
                   start_ms                    end_ms  diff
0  2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z  2020-09-01T08:11:19.336Z     0
1  2020-09-01T08:11:20.652Z  2020-09-01T08:11:20.662Z    10
2  2020-09-01T08:11:20.670Z  2020-09-01T08:11:20.688Z    18
```